# Preserving backslashes in post_content

Tags: php, database, hooks, latex

I am trying to preserve backslahes in "post_content". When I escape the content with another backslash, it gets saved into the database correctly. However the next time I load the page in admin to edit it, the backslash is unescaped. So when I save the page after edits, it disappears as PHP thinks I am trying to escape the character after it.

Example: `\\something` in page gets saved as `\something` in the database. The next time I load the page in admin, there's only `\something` (that's what's saved in the DB). If I save the page now, the backslash disappears and only `something` is saved.

I have tried `save_post` and `content_save_pre` hooks to manually add another backslash to escape "my" backslash. For some reason `str_replace()` worked for only the first few hundred characters of post_content.

Do you please have any better way to preserve backslashes without having to manually escape all of them when saving a page after editing?

Comment: This isn't normally an issue, what's the problem that you're trying to solve that requires special handling of backslashes to begin with? I can type backslashes into the editor and update posts fine without any loss or mangling

Comment: @Tom J Nowell I have forgotten to mention it, I am using the KingComposer plugin for building pages. You are right, I have just tried what I am trying to do with the standard editor and it works fine. Seems like the KingComposer's Text Block is mangling the post_content somehow. I guess my question is off-topic then, as it's related to a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: I haven't heard of that one before, I'd definitely mention it to them as an issue

Comment: Sent an e-mail a minute ago! Thanks a lot for your help, atleast I have localized the issue for now.